# Masonry script event on layout initialization

Tags: jquery-masonry

How to execute my function every time the [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) script reorganize elements, when a window resized for example?
In this example it works only first time.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#container').masonry({
     // layoutComplete: masonry_refreshed(), // <-- doesn't work propriety
        itemSelector: '.item'
    });

    masonry_refreshed();
});

function masonry_refreshed()
{
    alert('Masonry refreshed')
}
```

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HeuKw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check: http://masonry.desandro.com/events.html
you can use following masonry event:

```
msnry.on( 'layoutComplete', masonry_refreshed );
```

note that msnry is the name of the variable in which you defined masonry.

---

**EDIT:**
Full demo code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var container = document.querySelector('#container');
    var msnry = new Masonry(container,{
        itemSelector: '.item',
        columnWidth: 70
    });

    msnry.on( 'layoutComplete', masonry_refresh );

    function masonry_refresh(){
        console.log("Masonry resized!");
    }

});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Cd6ce/1/

---

**EDIT2:** If you really want to use it the jQuery way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        columnWidth: 70
    });
    var msnry = $('#container').data('masonry');
    msnry.on( 'layoutComplete', masonry_refresh );

    function masonry_refresh(){
        console.log("Masonry resized!");
    }

});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Cd6ce/4/

Comment: Sorry does not work... I've added working demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HeuKw  It alerts only first time, but not when resize window. I guess I need to create my own event on window resize...

Comment: or if you really want to use the jQuery way, then you need to get your masonry instance with `var msnry = $container.data('masonry');` and use the code i supplied. EDIT: Added to answer

Comment: Thank you Kristof for your help, I've found that this example doesn't work in Opera, but it works with `return true` at the end of `function masonry_refresh()`

Comment: Anything wrong with: http://jsfiddle.net/vrboooct/ ? Seems a bit easier to read to me.

Answer (score 2):

You have to disable 'layout' on initialization. See: http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html

```
msnry = new Masonry( self.el, {
    isInitLayout: false,
    itemSelector: '.brick'
});

msnry.on( 'layoutComplete', function(){
    console.log('completed');
});

msnry.layout();
```

Comment: This worked for me, since using the event binding method, it would only trigger after a window resize, but not on start. This method triggers the event on start and on window resize as well.

Thank you!